# Why isn't Makedev setting up when I'm trying to updgrade my ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

So I am updating my Ubuntu to 20.04 and everything is running smoothly up until the last second. Everything is unpackaging nicely, So after makedev unpackaged, the computer was trying to set up Makedev but for some reason it can't it says Aborting  MAKEDEV in invocation. Here is the script.

Setting up makedev (2.3.1-94) ...
/run/udev or .udevdb or .udev presence implies active udev.  Aborting MAKEDEV in
vocation.
/run/udev or .udevdb or .udev presence implies active udev.  Aborting MAKEDEV in
vocation.
/run/udev or .udevdb or .udev presence implies active udev.  Aborting MAKEDEV in
vocation.
/run/udev or .udevdb or .udev presence implies active udev.  Aborting MAKEDEV in
vocation.
/run/udev or .udevdb or .udev presence implies active udev.  Aborting MAKEDEV in
vocation.
/run/udev or .udevdb or .udev presence implies active udev.  Aborting MAKEDEV in
vocation.
/run/udev or .udevdb or .udev presence implies active udev.  Aborting MAKEDEV in
vocation.
/run/udev or .udevdb or .udev presence implies active udev.  Aborting MAKEDEV in
vocation.
/run/udev or .udevdb or .udev presence implies active udev.  Aborting MAKEDEV in
vocation.
/run/udev or .udevdb or .udev presence implies active udev.  Aborting MAKEDEV in
vocation.
/run/udev or .udevdb or .udev presence implies active udev.  Aborting MAKEDEV in
vocation.
chmod: cannot access '/dev/tty[0-9]*': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package makedev (--configure):
 installed makedev package post-installation script subprocess returned error ex
it status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 makedev

Any help to let MAKEDEV smoothly set up? I'm just trying to update ubuntu! Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Is MAKEDEV installed, and are you using SUDO?

Comment: Yes Makedev is installed and using SUDO and the problem is still happening. For some reason

Comment: Are you upgrading an existing distro to 20.04? Or is this a fresh install that you are applying updates too?

Comment: This is the first time upgrading to 20.04 if that helps anything.

Comment: So you are coming from 19* and are doing a dist-upgrade?

Comment: Hello I did sudo apt Dist-upgrade and this is what I get now. Lol I always run into problems.Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 dpkg amd64 1.19.7ubuntu3
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.19.7ubuntu3_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Comment: Okay I fixed the problem and makedev is still aborting even when doing sudo apt-dist upgrade

Answer (score 0):

I just hit this problem while upgrading a neglected Ubuntu virtual machine from Xenial (16.04) to Bionic (18.04) and then from Bionic (18.04) to Focal (20.04). During this last upgrade I hit the exact same error reported here. I resolved this issue by editing the post-installation script of the `makedev` package as follows:

```
--- /var/lib/dpkg/info/makedev.postinst~    2023-11-27 18:26:16.978386686 +0100
+++ /var/lib/dpkg/info/makedev.postinst 2023-11-27 18:26:35.698314327 +0100
@@ -34,7 +34,7 @@
    test -e /dev/$i || MAKEDEV $i
 done
 
-chmod g-r,o= /dev/tty[0-9]*
+chmod g-r,o= /dev/ttyS[0-9]*
 
 test -e /dev/random || MAKEDEV random
 test -e /dev/urandom || MAKEDEV urandom
```

After making this modification I ran `sudo apt-get install -f` which finished the aborted configuration of the `makedev` package (without fatal errors this time, because of the modification I made).

I use Linux KVM virtual machines and I have the `linux-image-kvm` package installed in the virtual machines. When I check for the presence of `/dev/tty*` device files this is what I find:

```
peter@unifi-controller:~$ ls -l /dev/tty*
crw-rw-rw- 1 root tty     5,  0 Nov 27 17:26 /dev/tty
crw--w---- 1 root tty     4, 64 Nov 27 17:26 /dev/ttyS0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 65 Nov 27 17:26 /dev/ttyS1
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 66 Nov 27 17:26 /dev/ttyS2
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 67 Nov 27 17:26 /dev/ttyS3
```

I suspect that the `do-release-upgrade` from Bionic to Focal was never tested in this specific scenario. In my opinion this is a bug in the `makedev` package, but fortunately it was easy enough for me to determine a workaround.